# Do ISCKON accept the authority of the Vedas?

Tags: iskcon

ISCKON is a sect of Hinduism who worship lord Krishna. They accept Bhagavata Puran and Gita(**to my current knowledge**).

Do they accept the authority of vedas *above gita*?

Comment: All the sectarian based cults, even though must accept *Vedas*, but will glorify their own texts that serve their purpose and deity. Even, all other scriptures, including the *Vedas*, even if non conforming to their sectarian ideology, will be interpreted(by the those cults) according to and in complete favour of, their own sectarian beliefs.

Comment: @Vivikta so do they accept vedas as authority above gita

Comment: That's opinion based, I guess. No one will explicitly say (at least from within the cult) that they give higher weightage to whichever text. In any way, they must accept Atleast the basic *Vedic* tenets, to be under the *Sanãtan Dharma* umbrella.

Comment: I can't comment if they do or not, in general, nothing & nothing, within the *Sanãtan Dharma*, is above the *Vedas*.

Comment: @Vivikta I don't think thay are cult. But rather I think of them as highly biased and obsessed with gita(no offense).

Comment: Everyone including us is biased, but ISCKON (in my opinion) are blatantly and aggressively biased. Thus, I completely refrain from reading and subscribing to their translation and interpretation of scriptures.

Comment: They accept the authority of Vedas in namesake. They attribute everything they say as coming from Vedas, although they don't quote any Vedic text in support.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As per their [official site](https://www.iskcon.org/) under the article [Studying Sacred Texts](https://www.iskcon.org/beliefs/studying-sacred-texts.php), They have mentioned only two texts. First is Bhagwat Gita, under which they say:

> **Bhagavad-Gita**
>
> **No sacred treatise, has a setting as intriguing as the Bhagavad Gita.** The dialogue between the princely warrior Arjuna and Lord Krishna, the Supreme Godhead before the onset of the Mahabharata War is universally renowned as the jewel of India’s spiritual wisdom.

Another text, they have mentioned is Vedas, they say:

> **Vedas**
>
> The word Veda can be traced to the sanskrit word vid which means “to know” or “knowledge.” The Vedic texts contain information on varied topics: from medicine to cosmology , from techniques of yoga and meditation to explanation of lessons in governmental organisation and military protocols.

So as per their official site, they do accept Vedas, however they give special place to Bhagwat Gita as we can notice the bold part.

Comment: Which book is higher gita or vedas for them

Comment: @DarkKnight, Gita is the essence of the Upanishads (Vedas) only so technically it doesn’t matter

Comment: @Archit yes, but there is a difference between vedas and the gita.